# Adapt this jQuery map to the screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to adapt a jQuery map to the screen resolution. This is my project link: http://comercialposadas.com/goodbarber/

And I use this code in the `mapplic.js` to resize the map:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    self.el.height($(window).height());
}).resize();
```

But the map doesn't show it.

Comment: do you want to make fullscreen the map in the bottom-right corner (in your website)?

Comment: @neoDev look the web now, you can see the map with OK weight, but the height doesnt adapt to the screen. I want to adapt to all resolutions (mobile, tablet, etc)

Comment: When asking a question like this where a link is provided to a live website, part of the question gets lost as soon as the code on that website is corrected. In order to preserve the question so that is of value to others it is a good idea to include all relevant code, and/or link to a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `height:100%;` either to the style of both the `html` and `body` elements, or to a CSS file that addresses them and change:

```
<div id="mapplic" class="mapplic-element" style="height: 420px;">
```

to

```
<div id="mapplic" class="mapplic-element" style="height: 100%;">
```

it will cause the map to be displayed at full height.

The reason for changing `html` and `body` as well as the `#mapplic` div is that height needs to be inherited from the root of the document in order to use `100%`.